# How to use CMSIS compiler libraries in arduino ide

Tags: c++, tensorflow, arduino, cmsis

I am trying to compile some tensor flow examples https://github.com/MDK-Packs/tensorflow-pack/tree/main/examples in arduino.
But it is not getting compiled, the error is

> In file included from
> C:\Users\Piruthivi\Documents\Arduino\libraries\Arduino_TensorFlowLite\src/tensorflow/lite/micro/tools/make/downloads/cmsis/CMSIS/DSP/Include/arm_math_types.h:76:0,
>
> ```
>              from C:\Users\Piruthivi\Documents\Arduino\libraries\Arduino_TensorFlowLite\src/tensorflow/lite/micro/tools/make/downloads/cmsis/CMSIS/DSP/Include/arm_math.h:199,
>
>              from C:\Users\Piruthivi\Documents\Arduino\libraries\Arduino_TensorFlowLite\src/tensorflow/lite/micro/tools/make/downloads/cmsis/CMSIS/NN/Include/arm_nnsupportfunctions.h:33,
>
>              from C:\Users\Piruthivi\Documents\Arduino\libraries\Arduino_TensorFlowLite\src/tensorflow/lite/micro/tools/make/downloads/cmsis/CMSIS/NN/Include/arm_nnfunctions.h:164,
>
>              from C:\Users\Piruthivi\Documents\Arduino\libraries\Arduino_TensorFlowLite\src\tensorflow\lite\micro\kernels\cmsis-nn\add.cpp:18:
> ```
>
> C:\Users\Piruthivi\Documents\Arduino\libraries\Arduino_TensorFlowLite\src/tensorflow/lite/micro/tools/make/downloads/cmsis/CMSIS/Core/Include/cmsis_compiler.h:54:25:
> fatal error: cmsis_gcc.h: No such file or directory
>
> compilation terminated.
>
> exit status 1
>
> Error compiling for board ESP32 Dev Module.
>
> This report would have more information with "Show verbose output
> during compilation" option enabled in File -> Preferences.

i dont know how to add cmsis library into arduino ide. solution will be very useful for me.
And thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The CMSIS-DSP library included with the Arduino Due board installation and CMSIS  package seem to contain lots of useful functions. By default in Arduino IDE its not possible. Therefore, to be able to called
CMSIS Library from Arduino IDE, DO THE BELOW MODIFICATIONS ON "platform.txt" where located in ...\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\arduino\hardware\sam\1.6.12.

... "{build.variant.path}/libarm_cortexM3l_math.a" to be added to platforms.txt in ## Combine gc-sections, archives, and objects, and the "libarm_cortexM3l_math.a" file to be copied to "..AppData\Local\arduino15\packages\arduino\hardware\sam\1.6.12\variants\arduino_due_x".
This works fine !, JPK

Answer (score 0):

CMSIS works with Arm microcontrollers so you will not be able to compile for Esp32 in Arduino. It will only work if the development boards you are using has an ARM processor.

You could use the Tensorflow Lite support for Esp32: https://github.com/tanakamasayuki/Arduino_TensorFlowLite_ESP32.
I have tested it and it works fine.